# Problem binding the values in combobox inside the datagridview

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview

I am developing the windows based application in which i need to bind the comboboxcolumns inside the datagridview with values from the [Attendance_type] table.  And the datasource of this datagridview will be from [Employees table].

I am currently doing this using this code.

```
dgvEmployee.Columns.Clear();
                dgvEmployee.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

                DataGridViewTextBoxColumn branchcolumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                branchcolumn.DataPropertyName = "Name";
                branchcolumn.HeaderText = "Employee Name";
                branchcolumn.Name = "Name";
                branchcolumn.Width = 200;
                dgvEmployee.Columns.Add(branchcolumn);

                var metaattend = from Metaatt in dataDC.Metaattend
                                 where Metaatt.Status == true
                                 orderby Metaatt.Metaname
                                 select Metaatt;
                List<Metaattend> obj_ma = new List<Metaattend>();
                obj_ma = metaattend.ToList();

                var Empvar = from Emp in dataDC.Employees
                             join dept in dataDC.Dept on Emp.Deptid equals dept.Id
                             join branch in dataDC.Branch on Emp.Branchid equals branch.Id
                             where Emp.Status == true & Emp.Name.Contains(txtbranch.Text)
                             & (Emp.Deptid == Convert.ToInt64(cmbDept.SelectedValue) | cmbDept.SelectedValue.ToString() == "0")
                             & (Emp.Branchid == Convert.ToInt64(cmbBranch.SelectedValue) | cmbBranch.SelectedValue.ToString() == "0")
                             orderby Emp.Name
                             select new { Emp.Id, Emp.Name };
                DataTable dt_employee = new DataTable();
                using (clsGeneral obj_gen = new clsGeneral())
                {
                    dt_employee = obj_gen.LINQToDataTable(Empvar);
                }
                dgvEmployee.DataSource = dt_employee;


                string[] datemonth = cmbMonth.Text.Split('-');
                int i = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt32(datemonth[1]), GetMonthNo(datemonth[0]));
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn daycomboColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                    daycomboColumn.HeaderText = (j + 1).ToString();
                    daycomboColumn.Width = 50;

                    daycomboColumn.DataSource = obj_ma;
                    daycomboColumn.DisplayMember = "Metaname";
                    daycomboColumn.ValueMember = "Id";
                    dgvEmployee.Columns.Add(daycomboColumn);
                }
```

Using this the code is executed successfully, but the form does not shows me any record in the column for combobox inside the datagridview.

This is the view of my form, when i click on the comboboxes then also it does not shows me anything.

[image]

I have seen many post about this but none was helpfull for me. As that all shows me the same thing that i have done.

Please help be with about where i have done the mistake.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there are records that match `Metaatt.Status == true` ?

Comment: yes there are 4 records in the list obj_ma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable Row Editing property for the datagridview was set to false. so it was not showing the Data inside the combobox.